# How do strongly typed HTML helpers work in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I understand if I put `@model` Product in my view then in the expression `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ProuctId)` the type of type lambda is `Func<Product, int>`. I can understand how the framework uses the lambda to get the value simply by just calling it but how does it get the string "ProductId" to use in the for the id and name properties of the input that is rendered? Can this somehow be obtained using reflection, if so how?

I've just noticed that the type of the parameter for `TextBoxFor` is actually `Expression<Func<Product, int>>` so am guessing `Expression` has something to do with the magic. It also raised the question of how does the lambda get automatically wrapped in an `Expression` object?

Comment: If "ProductId" in intellisense then check [Type Inference](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jaredpar/2007/12/14/c-lambda-type-inference/) and more understanding with help of [Custom HTML Helpers in MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs) and rest through reflection.

Comment: Study the [source code](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/InputExtensions.cs)